# Aligning and scaling ggplots with patchwork

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I'm trying to make a combine some plots into a single plot using the patchwork package, but I'm unfamiliar with it and am having trouble figuring out to how to properly scale the size of the plots. There's one core plot, the scatter plot, and then a boxplot for each continuous variable to some the distributions as well. Here's a reproducible example below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(100)
dat1 <- tibble(x = runif(1000, 0, 10),
               y = runif(1000, 0, 20),
               group1 = sample(rep(letters[1:5], each = 200)),
               group2 = sample(rep(letters[-22:-1], each = 250)))

plot1 <- ggplot(data = dat1) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = group1)) +
  facet_wrap(~group2) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')

xbox <- ggplot(data = dat1) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = x, y = group1, fill = group1, color = group1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(position = 'top') +
  theme(legend.position = 'none',
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        title = element_blank())

ybox <- ggplot(data = dat1) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = group1, y = y, fill = group1, color = group1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(position = 'right') +
  theme(legend.position = 'none',
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        title = element_blank())

(xbox + plot_spacer()) / (plot1 + ybox)
```

[image]

This is close to what I'm attempting, but the boxplots need to be rescaled such that the top one is approximately 20% of its shown height and the righthand one is approximately 20% of its shown width. I've tried using `patchwork::plot_layout` to handle the scaling, but I keep getting unexpected results. I inserted the `patchwork::plot_spacer()` so that the righthand boxplot wouldn't stretch the whole height of picture but maybe there is a better way to do that. The boxplots are supposed to appear more like axes, so that upper right whitespace shouldn't really be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain you'll get a plot that makes inferential sense in the margins, but you can change the widths and heights of the marginal plots in `plot_layout` using either the `heights` and `widths` arguments or the `design` argument. Note that plots in parenthesis are considered "subplots" themselves and is given their own "area" when using `plot_layout`. As such I've added all plots together rather than arranging them using other patchwork operators.

```
xbox + plot_spacer() + plot1 + ybox + plot_layout(design = c(area(t = 1, b = 1, l = 1, r = 6), # <== top column
                                                             area(t = 1, b = 1, l = 7, r = 7), # <== top right
                                                             area(t = 2, b = 7, l = 1, r = 6), # <== bottom left
                                                             area(t = 2, b = 7, l = 7, r = 7)  # <== bottom right
                                                             ))
# Alternative:
xbox + plot_spacer() + plot1 + ybox + plot_layout(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, 
                                                  heights = c(1, 6),
                                                  widths = c(6, 1))
```

[image]